# Rails update ActiveRecord from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im working on a simple app here that needs a settings page since I am new to rails I am a little lost here. I would like to get it setup in a database with one column as a key and one column as the value. I already have a few things setup here but I am having trouble getting my forms to update the settings working.

All I want to do is have a single settings page with multiple settings that can be changed in it. for now all settings are going to be text fields. With my current code im getting the error "undefined method `to_key' for #". so here is some code:

model: setting.rb

```
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if method_name[-1] == '='
      handle_set_setting method_name.to_s.delete("="), args.first
    else
      handle_get_setting method_name
    end
  end

  private

  def self.handle_get_setting(name)
    if setting = Setting.find_by(key: name.to_s)
      setting.value unless setting.value.empty?
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def self.handle_set_setting(name, value)
    if setting = Setting.find_or_create_by(key: name.to_s)
      setting if setting.update(value: value.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my settings_controller.rb (Im 100% sure I dont have much correct in here.)

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_settings, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
  end

  def new
    @settings = Setting.new
  end


  def update
    @settings.update(params)
  end

  private

     def params
        params.require(:key).permit(:value, :etc)
     end
     def set_settings
       @settings = Setting.find params[:key]
     end

end
```

and here is my index.html.erb (pretty sure this is all wrong)

```
<h2> Settings </h2>

<h3> Movie Settings </h3>
<%= form_for(@settings) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden :key => "cp_api" %>
<%= f.label :value %><br>
<%= f.text_field :value %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the error log:

```
Started GET "/settings" for ::1 at 2015-09-18 00:57:24 -0400
Processing by SettingsController#index as HTML
  Setting Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "settings".* FROM "settings"
  Rendered settings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_key' for # <Setting::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa186b88128>):
    1: <h2> Settings </h2>
    2:
    3: <h3> Settings </h3>
    4: <%= form_for(@settings) do |f| %>
    5: <%= f.hidden :key => "cp_api" %>
    6: <%= f.label :value %><br>
    7: <%= f.text_field :value %>
  app/views/settings/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_settings_index_html_erb__4580226212883122031_70165864193720'
```

Im sure its something really easy to figure out, but I'm just really     lost here, Ive been bashing my head for 2 days on this problem and I just     cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: At which line you get that error? Can you post the error log in the question?

Comment: Try to change `params.require(:key).permit(:value, :etc)` to `params.require(:setting).permit(:value, :etc)`

Comment: @Pavan added error log, error is in line 4 of index.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@setting = Setting.New` to your `index` method like below

```
def index
  @settings = Setting.all
  @setting = Setting.new
end
```

and change `<%= form_for(@settings) do |f| %`> to `<%= form_for(@setting) do |f| %>`

Also you need to change your `params` method to below

```
def params
  params.require(:setting).permit(:value, :key)
end
```

And change `<%= f.hidden :key => "cp_api" %>` to <`%= f.hidden_field :key => "cp_api" %>` to avoid further issues

Comment: alright! that got it to work for the most part, however now I am getting the 
error SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:33:in `params'